# How to convert .getJSON to .ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

How can I convert this:

```
    var dataURL = 'http://example.com/data.json';
    var queryOptions = {
        start: Date.parse('today - 15 years').getTime()/1000,
        end: Date.parse('today').getTime()/1000
    }

    $.getJSON(dataURL, queryOptions, function(jsonresult) {
```

...to a jQuery .ajax call?

Comment: The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) for `$.getJSON()` includes the equivalent `$.ajax()` syntax. Did you read it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url: dataURL
    data: queryOptions,
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(jsonresult){
        //json here
    }
});
```

Although, `$.getJSON()` is just a shorthand JSON prepared wrapper for the `$.ajax()` method.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: dataURL,
    dataType: "json",
    data: queryOptions,
    success: function(result) {
        //
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        //
    }
});
```